# Latex cannot read my bib file

Tags: bibliographies

I cannot make Latex read my bib file
here is the code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Hello
\cite{Willis2009} 

\bibliographystyle{dcu} 
\bibliography{1_ref_bib}

\end{document}
```

Willis2009 is in the bib file

Comment: TeXnically speaking, LaTeX doesn't read the contents of a `.bib` file; parsing the contents of bib files is BibTeX's job. Did you run BibTeX after running LaTeX (followed by two more LaTeX runs)? What error and/or warning messages are in the `.blg` ("BibTeX log") file? Is the bib file named `1_ref_bib.bib`? Can BibTeX find the file `1_ref_bib.bib`?

Answer (score 2):

The code below works.

The `dcu` bibliography style is part of the `harvard` package. Be sure to load either `harvard` or the `natbib`/`har2nat` pair of packages in the preamble. The `filecontents` business is just in lieu of a "real" bib file; you can take that stuff out if you already have a bib file.

*EDIT*

Run latex (pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex, whatever), then bibtex, then latex twice more. Your bib file should be in the same folder as your latex file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{harvard}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{1_ref_bib.bib}
@article{Willis2009,
    author={Willie Willis},
    title={How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck would chuck wood?},
    year={2009}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    Hello
    \cite{Willis2009} 

    \bibliographystyle{dcu} 
    \bibliography{1_ref_bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You already did that in a comment, though, but I guess repetition doesn't hurt.

Comment: How to run bibtex?

Comment: I come up with this mistake

Comment: This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9) The top-level auxiliary file: test4.aux The style file: dcu.bst I couldn't open database file 1_ref_bib.bib ---line 4 of file test4.aux : \bibdata{1_ref_bib : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no database files---while reading file test4.aux Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Willis2009" (There were 2 error messages)

Comment: It cannot find 1_ref_bib.bib   Make sure it's in the same folder as your latex file.

Comment: It is indeed. It is here. I am desperated

Comment: Sorry, but that's what the error message means.  Just make sure that the file name is exactly the same as what's in the \bibliography command followed by .bib.  So here it should be 1_ref_bib.bib .

Comment: I have tried everything. The file is there, the name is right. Nothing works. I will uninstall Latex and install everything again.

Comment: Don't do that.  That's not the problem.

Comment: I had Latex in my PC when I was working in anoter city. It worked well! I copied the entire hard disk and moved to my dropbox. I am using these files but now it cannot read my bibtex despite of the fact that these files are in the same folder, that nothing has apparently changed.

Answer (score -1):

See this answer: https://texblog.org/2011/12/12/bib2tex-converting-bibtex-to-bibitems/.

bib2tex: Converting bibtex to bibitems
12. December 2011 by tom    3 Comments

A friend asked me today to help him convert a bibtex-file to a \LaTeX bibliography (\bibitem{}), since the journal he submits his paper to doesn’t accept bibtex-files (*.bib). So what we were trying to do is to convert a set of bibtex-references of the following form (from cell):
@article{bartel2009,
    Author = {Bartel, David P. },
    Date = {2009/01/23},
    Journal = {Cell},
    Month = {01},
    Number = {2},
    Pages = {215--233},
    Title = {Micro{RNA}s: Target Recognition and Regulatory Functions},
    Volume = {136},
    Year = {2009}}

to a format that \LaTeX understands, e.g.:
\bibitem[Bartel(2009)]{bartel2009}
David~P. Bartel.
\newblock Micro{RNA}s: Target recognition and regulatory functions.
\newblock \emph{Cell}, 136\penalty0 (2):\penalty0 215--233, 01 2009.

There is an easy way of converting references by making use of the bibtex-command. It does exactly what we needed in the background. Typesetting the document once (latex) and generating the references with the bibtex-command will create a metafile called “document.bbl”, containing all the referenced bibitems in \LaTeX-format.

Comment: Any chance of something similar working with BibLaTeX? I tried to repeat the same strategy, but the .bll file does not contain things that the .tex file is likely to understand (instead of "bibitem" it has "entry" and the whole syntax looks completely different to me.