# How do I convert my bibliography items from BibTeX to an embedded format?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, conversion

There exist two major ways of defining a bibliography:

1. Embedded

   Declare `\begin{thebibliography}` at the end of your file and use \bibitem .  The entries look like

   ```
   \bibitem{amin1}
     S.~P. Beeby, M.~J. Tudor, and N.~White, ``Energy harvesting vibration sources
     for microsystems applications,'' {\em Measurement science and
     technology}~{\bf 17}(12), p.~R175, 2006.
   ```
2. Using BibTeX- The entries are stored in a .bib file. The entries look like :-

   ```
    @article{amin1,
     title={Energy harvesting vibration sources for microsystems applications},
     author={Beeby, S Pꎬ and Tudor, M Jꎬ and White, NM},
     journal={Measurement science and technology},
     volume={17},
     number={12},
     pages={R175},
     year={2006},
     publisher={IOP Publishing}
   }
   ```

Is there an easy, automated way to convert entries from 2 to 1.

I have been using format 2, i.e using a bib file. But I want to switch to format 1 without manually changing all the entries.   Is this possible?

Comment: going from 1 to 2 is exactly (and all) bibtex does,

Comment: see for example the answer to another question today http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351230/latex-cannot-read-my-bib-file  the input is a `bib` file like your (2) but running `bibtex` genrates a `bbl` file which is a `bibliography` environment like your (1).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle,  Thanks for answering.  I have updated the question. I guess it was not very clear.

Comment: @AdityaNanda: Converting from (2) to (1) is done via BibTeX, as already mentioned. Also, the process can be automated in most editors.

Comment: @AdityaNanda it was clear, and the answer is the same, converting from (2) to (1_ is all bibtex can do

Comment: Note that you should always store the references in your (2) format and then just translate to (1) for each document using the style required for that document.

Comment: @AdityaNanda yes bbl files are always a generated bibliography, So what do you want to do that isn't just the normal use of bibtex?

Answer (score 4):

The conversion from a BibTeX `.bib` file to an embedded `thebibliography` environment depends on the bibliography *style* you're after. The style defines the layout and formatting of specific `@type` references.

The suggestion would be to:

1. Use BibTeX to compile your file under the specific style you're interested in. For example,

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage{filecontents}
   \begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
   @article{greenwade93,
     author = {George D. Greenwade},
     title = {The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})},
     year = {1993},
     journal = {TUGBoat},
     volume = {14},
     number = {3},
     pages = {342--351}
   }
   \end{filecontents*}

   \begin{document}

   \nocite{*}

   \bibliographystyle{plain}
   \bibliography{references}

   \end{document}
   ```

   When compiled using LaTeX > BibTeX > LaTeX > LaTeX, the above minimal example (called `filename.tex`) creates `filename.bbl`:

   ```
   \begin{thebibliography}{1}

   \bibitem{greenwade93}
   George~D. Greenwade.
   \newblock The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN}).
   \newblock {\em TUGBoat}, 14(3):342--351, 1993.

   \end{thebibliography}
   ```

   BibTeX already took care of the formatting and layout, as well as the sort order (if that has been specified in some way, even using a different package).
2. Exchange

   ```
   \bibliographystyle{plain}
   \bibliography{references}
   ```

   for

   ```
   \input{filename.bbl}
   ```

   in your code.

[image]

Comment: Also see [Edifix](https://edifix.com/) (a [small write-up about it](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/446-edifix-converts-unstructured-bibliographies-to-bibtex#.WJC3a_nR_Dc)).

Comment: Thansks for the answer. I ran the minimal example in 1, did run well but it created a "references.bib" not 'filename.bib'.

Further, I am looking for a method to transfer bib entries from one to another in an automated way.  I have added new stuff in question details ~too long to put here.

Comment: Any chance of something similar working with BibLaTeX? I tried to repeat the same strategy, but the .bll file does not contain things that the .tex file is likely to understand (instead of "bibitem" it has "entry" and the whole syntax looks completely different to me.

Comment: @Brightsun: [`biblatex`](//ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) completely changes the syntax of how the bibliography functions. That's also why the `.bbl` also starts out checking whether you've loaded `biblatex`, otherwise it doesn't read any of the file contents. Since it does stem from a `.bib` which has a common syntax, it might be better to see if you can make your own bibliography style that matches what you've created with `biber`, only this time with BibTeX.

Comment: OK @Werner, then I should probably master another package such as natbib or the one you employed in the example, if I plan to make these conversions often. In the end I managed with converting from the bll from natbib but I had to change manually a LOT of stuff...

Comment: OK, converting from 2 to 1 is easy. Is it also possible to convert from 1 (embedded) to 2 (bibtex) ?

Comment: @florin: Not that I know of.

Comment: If you're using any IDE like Texstudio in my case, then LaTex means compiling the code (F6) and BibTex means compiling the bibliography only (F8).  Thanks to @sigur https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156206/220115 here.