# How do I convert my bibliography from embedded format to BibTeX?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Is it  possible to convert bibliographies from  embedded to  bibtex ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. At the current state, it is not clear what you are asking for. What do you mean by **embedded** format?

Comment: I was citing https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351241/how-do-i-convert-my-bibliography-items-from-bibtex-to-an-embedded-format/515022#515022 " There exist two major ways of defining a bibliography:
1) Embedded Declare \begin{thebibliography} at the end of your file and use \bibitem  ... 
 2) Using BibTeX-.... @article{..."     Is it also possible to convert from 1) (embedded) to 2) (bibtex) ?

Comment: Given the silence, I guess the only way to convert from  embedded bibliography to  bibtex is to change  all the \bibitem to @article manually